# Block Proxy Access to App on Django

Tags: python, django, proxy

I would like to prevent users that are behind a proxy from registering on my Django app. I hear that there is no perfect way to block proxies, but can I get some ideas on the most efficient means of doing so? I would like to prevent as many proxies from slipping through as possible.

I have already found this snippet:

```
if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
|| $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']
|| $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']
|| $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']
|| $_SERVER['HTTP_VIA']
|| in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'], array(8080,80,6588,8000,3128,553,554))
|| @fsockopen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 80, $errno, $errstr, 30))
{
     exit('Proxy detected');
}
```

It's php, but that can be translated to Python easily enough. Is there anything else I can do to improve my chances?